# distribution of prime numbers

Tags: logic

we all know that primes are special numbers, but let me ask you one thing that 'if we change the base of our widely used decimal to something else, lets say to octal, would the distribution of primes also change; or it is irrespective of the number system we use ?'

also if more basically we adopt binary number system which numbers would we call primes and how would sieve work ?

ask me if you are still not getting my question

Comment: Different number bases are just different ways of writing numbers down, they don't mean anything about the actual numbers themselves.

Comment: The number five is a prime, whether you write it in decimal as $5$, in binary as $101$, or as roman numeral $V$. The same applies to all other primes. Don't confuse the notation with the number itself and its properties.

Comment: See also possible duplicate https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2842305/505767

Answer (score 2):

Eleven times thirteen is one hundred forty-three, hence one hundred forty-three isn't prime.

This is true if we write one hundred forty-three as $143_{10}$, or as $217_8$, or as $10001111_2$.

Comment: just let me know that how can we check if a binary is prime or not, for instance 2 in decimals is 100 in binary, and how can I know it by sieve or anything ?

Comment: You can check if something in binary is prime or not just by checking if it is divisible by every prime number that is smaller then that number.

Comment: but if we are following some other base, say 8 and we represent a number in that one its value being 43, ( if this were a decimal then the number is prime ) but when we convert it in real decimals its value is 35. now the problem arise to me that if we change the base of numbers even primes are no longer primes and the so called special numbers lose their speciality

Comment: @tusharhsim $35_{10}$ does not magically become a prime if you write it $43_8$. This is because $5_8\cdot7_8=43_8$. You seem to be confusing the concepts of a number and its presentation/notation. Primality is about divisibility, and the definition of divisibility is immune to notation (otherwise divisibility would not be a well defined concept).

Comment: @Jyrki Lahtonen thanks for your answer I really messed up with concepts

Comment: Vadim, sorry about forgetting to upvote your explanation the first time I visited this thread :-)