# are primes really special

Tags: logic

if we are following some other base other than 10, say 8 and we represent a number its value being 43 ( if this were a decimal then the number would be prime ). 
but when we convert it in decimals ( as it were not a decimal in the first place ) its value is 35.
now the problem arises to me that if we change the base of numbers even primes are no longer primes and the so called special numbers lose their specialty.

Comment: Perform trial division, for example

Comment: What part of this [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2846271/distribution-of-prime-numbers#comment5870617_2846271) to your previous question is not clear? `The number five is a prime, whether you write it in decimal as 5, in binary as 101, or as roman numeral V. The same applies to all other primes. Don't confuse the notation with the number itself and its properties.` How you check for primality of a number has nothing to do with bases, or any other ways to represent numbers.

Comment: There's no such thing as a "binary number". The binary system is just a way of writing numbers, a notation system.

Comment: 43, base 8 wasn't prime to begin with.

Comment: @David Diaz I got it, thanks

Answer (score 1):

OK if it ends in $0$ and it is not $10$ then it is not prime (as it must have $2$ as a factor and not be $2$). After that, it might get tricky :)

Basically I think there are a bunch of 'division rules' that show that numbers are not prime. For example, in base 10 we can say that if a number ends in a five then five is a factor or if the sum of the digits is divisible by three then the number itself is divisible by three. In binary, for example, if the number consists of a string of $1$s then we know it is divisible by nine (for three or more $1$s) or three (for $2$ or more $1$s). More rules will be discoverable.

Comment: what about 15, its binary value is 1111

Comment: @tusharhsim 1111 is composite in any base: $(b^2+1)(b+1)$

Comment: $11111_2$ is $31_{10}$ is prime.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in the comments, your question is oddly phrased. A number $n$ written in binary doesn't gain or lose any properties when you write it in a different base.

> "A rose by any other name would smell as sweet."- All the mathematicians, emoting

There are, however, shortcuts to confirming compositeness that depend on the way the number is written. For example, in decimal, numbers whose digits sum to a multiple of 3 are themselves divisible by 3. Here's another general rule:

Consider the number $1111$ written in some unknown base $b \in \mathbb{N}$. What can you say about it? All you know is that it is a number that can be represented as a polynomial in b:

$$n = 1(b^3) + 1(b^2) +1(b^1) +1(b^0) $$

Well, this is a factorable polynomial:

$$b^3 + b^2 +b^1+b^0 =(b^2+1)\cdot(b+1) $$

And thus is composite.

By changing bases, this factorization might not be as easy to see but will still exist.